# How to fix Duplicity B2 (Backblaze) error

Tags: backup, duplicity

When running Duplicity to backup to B2 (Backblaze) it fails with the following error:

```
Attempt 1 failed. AttributeError: B2ProgressListener instance has no attribute '__exit__'
Attempt 2 failed. AttributeError: B2ProgressListener instance has no attribute '__exit__'
Attempt 3 failed. AttributeError: B2ProgressListener instance has no attribute '__exit__'
Attempt 4 failed. AttributeError: B2ProgressListener instance has no attribute '__exit__'
Giving up after 5 attempts. AttributeError: B2ProgressListener instance has no attribute '__exit__'
```

I run it with the following command line:

```
  duplicity ~ b2://account:key@bucket
```

There is an empty file created in the B2 bucket, so access to the cloud seems to be working.  What is wrong with my setup?

Ubuntu is version 16.04.
Python is version 2.7.12.
Duplicity is version 0.7.17.
b2 backend is 1.3.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

should be fixed in duplicity 0.7.18 released yesterday

> - Fixed bug #1785520 with patch from Chris Hunt
>
>   - Fix for B2 version 1.3.4 just released

https://launchpad.net/duplicity/+milestone/0.7.18

..ede/duply.net

Comment: Well, on all our servers the issue started to occur just after upgrade from duplicity 0.7.17 to duplicity 0.7.18! So it's a regression bug. 0.7.17 worked flawlessly!

Comment: I've opened new bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1788599

Comment: Just FYI, if you need 0.7.18 _now_ (like we did on prod), you can find it on duplicity-team's PPA: https://launchpad.net/~duplicity-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: My own comment helped me out nearly a year later. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a known bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1785520

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067296/how-to-fix-duplicity-b2-backblaze-error#comment1750938_1067749

Comment: I've opened new bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1788599