# After upgrade, Duplicity with B2 Backblaze error

Tags: dependencies, backup, duplicity, sdk

I just upgraded to 21.04 and started getting an error with using Duplicity with B2.

Duplicity is version 0.8.17
b2 is version 2.5.0
b2sdk is 1.9.0

Each seems to work individually. When I try to run a simple test backup, the following happens

```
duplicity test.png b2://xxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxx@my-bucket
BackendException: B2 backend requires B2 Python SDK (pip install b2sdk)
```

[Similar questions have been asked in the past](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128332/duplicity-with-b2-backblaze-issue), but the issue there seemed to be with a previous version of Duplicity, so I'm not sure what is happening there. The answers suggested in the linked question did not work for me.

I have also tried removing and reinstalling each of Duplicity, b2, and b2sdk.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you figure it out? I suddenly started having this issue on Mint 19.3.

Answer (score 1):

Prompted by a comment checking in on this, I will provide what ended up working for me. I removed slashes from my B2 key as suggested by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1128942). I did likewise for the encryption key, passphrase, etc. just to be safe. Been working fine since then.